# How to return window state back to normal after debugging

Tags: xcode

When I run my project in Xcode a few things happen (especially if there was an exception)

- The debug (output) window slides up into view
- The file directory pane on the left switches to the Debug navigator
- The code file you left off on switches to main.m or some other file where the error happened.

That's all great, but when I'm done running the application none of this goes back to how it was. So that means there's this constant repetition of hiding the output window, clicking on the file directory icon, and finding the file I was just on.

This is just completely unacceptable as I may run the application a dozen times in a minute.

Coming from Visual Studio, the same experience happens when debugging, but everything returns back to normal when you stop debugging.

How can I make things return back to normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Xcode 4 or later, you can set up behaviors to set up things how you want. Under the Xcode Preferences, click on the Behaviors tab and select "Completes" under the "Running" section. You have the option to open or close any of the various panes.

[Here's an interesting article](http://brian-webster.tumblr.com/post/22060296528/how-to-make-xcode-4s-ui-work-for-you-maybe) on customizing Xcode to make it work better for you.